# PHP ODBC: field names are truncated to 1 character when running in CLI

Tags: php, odbc

Decided to put my script in `/etc/crontab` instead of running it from the browser, but realized that I'm getting different results.

Running script from the browser:

```
Array
(
    [ACTIVE] => C  
    [CUSTOMER_NUM] => 123
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] => 123 CORP                
    [REPNUM] => 099
    [ADDRESS1] => IDD# 123                           
    [ADDRESS2] => P O BOX 123
    [CITY] => CLEVELAND                
    [STATE] => OH 
    [ZIP] => 44136       
    [REPNAME] => House Account                 
    [PHONENUM] => 123
)
```

Running script from `php-cli`:

```
Array
(
    [A] => P O BOX 123
    [C] => CLEVELAND
    [R] => House Account
    [S] => OH
    [Z] => 44136
    [P] => 123
)
```

So I wonder why associative array keys are truncated? Please help. Thanks.

Script:

```
  $result = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT
CAST(F0101JC.ABAT1 as varchar(20) CCSID 37) as Active,
F0101JC.ABAN8 as CUSTOMER_NUM,
F0101JC.ABALPH as CUSTOMER_NAME,
CAST(F0101JC.ABAC02 as varchar(20) CCSID 37) as RepNum,
F0101JC.ALADD1 as Address1,
F0101JC.ALADD2 as Address2,
F0101JC.ALCTY1 as City,
CAST(F0101JC.ALADDS as varchar(20) CCSID 37) as State,
CAST(F0101JC.ALADDZ as varchar(20) CCSID 37) as Zip,
F0005.DRDL01 as RepName,
trim(CAST(F0115.WPAR1 as varchar(20) CCSID 37))  || '-' || trim(CAST(F0115.WPPH1 as varchar(20) CCSID 37)) as PhoneNum
FROM CLTPRDDTA.F0101JC \"F0101JC\"
LEFT JOIN GENCOM.F0005 \"F0005\"
ON \"F0101JC\".\"ABAC02\" = trim(\"F0005\".\"DRKY\")
LEFT JOIN CLTPRDDTA.F0115 F0115
ON F0101JC.ABAN8 = F0115.WPAN8
WHERE  DRSY = '01  '
AND DRRT = '02'
AND WPRCK7 = '1'
AND F0101JC.ABAT1 = 'C'
  ");

  while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )) {
    print_r($myRow);
  }
```

Versions:

```
php.x86_64                       5.6.22-1.el7.remi                   @remi-php56
php-cli.x86_64                   5.6.22-1.el7.remi                   @remi-php56
php-odbc.x86_64                  5.6.22-1.el7.remi                   @remi-php56
httpd.x86_64                     2.4.6-40.el7.centos                 @base
libphp5.so
```

Comment: Try setting LANG=C

Comment: export LANG=C  (before running the script) or "LANG=C php /path/to/the/script.php"